# Set of numbers pairwise relatively prime

Tags: number-theory, logic, prime-numbers

Given a positve integer n, we can find infinitely many positve integers $b$ such that the $n-1$ integers in the set $\{b+1,\,2b+1,\,3b+1,\,...,\,(n-1)b+1\}$ are pairwise relatively prime.

I assume that $b+1,\,2b+1,\,3b+1,\,...,\,(n-1)b+1$ are not r.p..

Let $1\le i<j\le n-1$ and $ib+1,jb+1$ are not r.p..

Let $p$ be a prime which is a factor of both $ib+1,\,jb+1$.

Question: Why should $p$ now $p\ge n-1$ ?

Proof finish:
$$
\begin{align*}
&p\mid (jb+1)-(ib+1)=(j-i)b\\
\Rightarrow& p\mid j-i\\
\Rightarrow& j-i<n-1\\
\Rightarrow& p<n-1,
\end{align*}
$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: The problem with your argument is that it is possible that $i=j$, and every integer divides $0$, so the last step $p \lt n-1$ is unjustified.

Comment: @DanBrumleve But we are trying to prove that, if $i\neq j$, then $ib+1$ and $jb+1$ are relatively prime. So how can it happen that $i=j$?

Comment: Would you mind reformulating your question. It might be me, but I am not entirely sure what you are asking. Clearly among the numbers of the form $1 + 2 i$ there are non-coprime pairs, such as $1 + 2$ and $1 + 8$.

Comment: Ok I just edited it. I refer to the whole set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can choose $b$, so take $$b=c\prod_{p \text{prime} \atop p \leq n-2}{p}$$ where $c$ is any positive integer. This gives infinitely many $b$. The rest follows from what you have done, as the prime factor cannot divide $b$, it must be $\geq n-1$.